# Having trouble getting textarea to work with rails/angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple feedback form on my rails/angular app.

I've create the form in a template,

```
%form
  %input{"ng-model" => "feedbackForm.name", :type => "text", :placeholder => "Name"}
  %textarea{"ng-model" => "feedbackForm.feedback", :type => "text", :placeholder => "Feedback"}
  %button{:value => "send", "ng-click" => "send()"}Send
```

In my feedbackCtrl I have the create function,

```
createFeedback.create({
  name:      $scope.feedbackForm.name,
  feedback:  $scope.feedbackForm.feedback
})
```

And a simple feedbackService,

```
app.factory('createFeedback', ['$http', function($http){
  return{
    create: function(feedback){
      return $http.post('/feedback.json', feedback);
    }
  };
}])
```

On the angular side things seem to work.

I've create the feedback resource in my routes,

```
resources :feedback, only:      [:create, :destroy, :index, :show]
```

And this is the rails feedback controller,

```
def create
   @feedback = Feedback.find_or_create_by feedback_params
   redirect_to :root
end

private
def feedback_params
  params.require(:feedback).permit(
    :name,
    :feedback
  )
end
```

And the table for feedback,

```
create_table "feedbacks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

When I use the form to send some data I get this error,

```
Started POST "/feedback.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-22 22:24:39 +0100
Processing by FeedbackController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Sometext", "feedback"=>"Some more text"}
  User Load (12.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 12.5ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "Some more text":String):
  app/controllers/feedback_controller.rb:19:in `feedback_params'
  app/controllers/feedback_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

So it looks to me like there's a problem with the rails controller, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at parameters you sent from client:

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"Sometext", "feedback"=>"Some more text"}
```

Feedback is just a string, but you try to require it as hash:

```
params.require(:feedback).permit(
  :name,
  :feedback
)
```

Posible fix:

```
params.permit(
  :name,
  :feedback
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty basic with Rails. Seems it kinda worked, but it creates a new problem though. `Unpermitted parameter: format` and `Feedback Load (4.7ms)  SELECT  "feedbacks".* FROM "feedbacks" WHERE "feedbacks"."name" = ? AND "feedbacks"."feedback" = 'asdasd asd' LIMIT 1  [["name", "Peter Boomsma"]]` for some reason it changes `feedback` to `feedbacks`.

Comment: "feedbacks" is a table name (plural), so it is ok, `find_or_create_by` looks for existent record, have you already created a record with the same params?

Comment: No I havent created an existing record. I thought find_or_create_by would check if a record already exisits.

Comment: Ah I see, how dumb. In my angular I give the parameter `feedback` while in my schema its `description`. Solved.